# Kotlin override ambiguity

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus

I have to create a custom logging provider for my Quarkus application to convert the log entries to the Google Cloud JSON format.
For this, the provider class (which is written in Kotlin) has to extend an abstract class called `ExtFormatter` (from a 3rd-party lib, written in Java), which has these two methods:

```
package org.jboss.logmanager;
[...]

public abstract class ExtFormatter extends Formatter {
   public final String format(final LogRecord record) {
      return format(ExtLogRecord.wrap(record));
   }

   [...]
}

public abstract String format(ExtLogRecord record);
```

`ExtLogRecord` is a subclass of `LogRecord`, so the method signatures are quite similar.
My logging provider implements the abstract method like this:

```
import io.quarkiverse.loggingjson.JsonProvider
import org.jboss.logmanager.ExtFormatter
import org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord
[...]

class JsonLoggingProvider : JsonProvider, ExtFormatter() {
   override fun format(extLogRecord: ExtLogRecord?) = null
}
```

When I run the application (not at compile time), I get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.mycompany.logging.JsonLoggingProvider_Subclass overrides final method org.jboss.logmanager.ExtFormatter.format(Ljava/util/logging/LogRecord;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:437)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:397)
        at com.mycompany.logging.JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.create(JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.zig:368)
        at com.mycompany.logging.JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.create(JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.zig:394)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at com.mycompany.logging.JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.get(JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.zig:426)
        at com.mycompany.logging.JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.get(JsonLoggingProvider_Bean.zig:442)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getBeanInstance(InstanceImpl.java:210)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl$InstanceIterator.next(InstanceImpl.java:246)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at io.quarkiverse.loggingjson.LoggingJsonRecorder.initializeJsonLogging(LoggingJsonRecorder.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LoggingJsonProcessor$setUpFormatter-614569086.deploy_0(LoggingJsonProcessor$setUpFormatter-614569086.zig:88)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LoggingJsonProcessor$setUpFormatter-614569086.deploy(LoggingJsonProcessor$setUpFormatter-614569086.zig:40)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:666)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:98)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

For some reason the wrong method (or both methods?) seem to be overridden.
I suspect that it happens because the methods have more or less the same signature.
Is there a way to make the Kotlin override more precise to avoid this issue?

Comment: I'm pretty confused with your description. You sometimes say you need a formatter, sometimes a log record and sometimes a logging provider. Is this all a single class? I guess not as you can't extend two abstract classes at the same time. So where exactly the clash happens? It would be easier if you would provide more code. I'm also concerned that you get your error on runtime, because such problem should be really reported on compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, the terminology is indeed confusing, sorry about that.
I tried to show only the relevant parts, but apparently I left out too much. I added some more code, hopefully that helps.
As you can see (now), it's just one class implementing an interface and extending an abstract class.

Comment: This is really interesting. No, I think it shouldn't be a problem in Kotlin. In fact, I just copied your code (only removed `JsonProvider`) and I was able to instantiate `JsonLoggingProvider` and call its `format()` method passing `ExtLogRecord`. What version of Kotlin do you use? Still, I'm concerned that this is a runtime error. Do you know what components prints this error message? Is it an exception or just a warning/error somewhere in logs?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to investigate this! By now I think you're absolutely right, it's not a problem in Kotlin. I've updated the stacktrace and it looks like it's related to the Quarkus Dependency Injection. In fact, when I started the application in Quarkus Dev mode and instructed it to dump the generated classes (those weird zig files you see in the stacktrace), the startup failed due to an `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException` related to the logging provider. I'm still not sure how to solve this properly, but I found a workaround that I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to my initial assumption, the problem is apparently not caused by Kotlin, but by Quarkus. Dependency injection seems to be confused by the very similar methods. Since I cannot change any method names or signatures because they're from the 3rd party Quarkiverse library, I worked around the issue by no longer subclassing `ExtFormatter`, but instead instantiating an already existing subclass of it called `JsonFormatter`:

```
import io.quarkiverse.loggingjson.JsonGenerator
import io.quarkiverse.loggingjson.JsonProvider
import org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord
import org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.JsonFormatter
[...]

class JsonLoggingProvider : JsonProvider {
  private val jsonFormatter = JsonFormatter()
  
  private fun writeMessage(generator: JsonGenerator, event: ExtLogRecord) {
      val message = jsonFormatter.formatMessage(event)
      [...]
  }
}
```

Thanks again [broot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448875/broot) for helping me out!